# How many ter'angreal did the Black Ajah steal?

Tags: the-wheel-of-time

In *The Shadow Rising* we have this quote from Egwene:

> Two recovered meant that eleven still with the Black Ajah (pg 198 kindle)

They have recovered two of the *ter'angreal* the Black Ajah had stolen, and from my understanding the 13 Black Ajah members who left the Tower took with them 13 *ter'angreal*. But what about the one Perrin broke, the hedgehog? Does Egwene not know Perrin destroyed one? Was that one not part of the 13 stolen?

Answer (score 4):

They stole thirteen dream ter'angreal, and at least had two others - the hedgehog, and the black rod that produces balefire.